# Is there a book or lecture notes on Percolation Theory containing exercises?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, percolation

I have seen Grimmett's Percolation Theory and I have also seen a few online lecture notes. But they don't have exercises.

I understand it is stupid to ask of exercises in such a recent and hot research topic, which is not yet well-developed, but I want to do a formal course on the subject and therefore need some exercises.

Can you please direct me to the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: These notes seem to have quite a few exercises sprinkled within the chapters: http://www.math.chalmers.se/~steif/perc.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for a modern account, i would advise Duminil-Copin:
https://www.unige.ch/~duminil/teaching/percolation/polycopie.pdf.
It's in french but the exercises are very good.
Also Ariel Yadin:
https://www.math.bgu.ac.il/~yadina/percolation.pdf
exercises are also very good.
Both of them are from the same school of thoughts.
A book is dealing with a more abstract setting and has become a Bible (for me), soon to be published at CUP:
http://mypage.iu.edu/~rdlyons/prbtree/prbtree.html
The Bollobas/Riordan is also a standard reference in percolation, with good exercises.

Answer (score 2):

Stauffer, Dietrich; Aharony, Anthony (1994), Introduction to Percolation Theory (2nd ed.), CRC Press, ISBN 978-0-7484-0253-3

I used this for my thesis and it is pretty good.

Comment: Thanks. But, it is highly non-linear and I doubt it approaches the topic in a "nice" way, as does Grimmett. I may be wrong but the treatment is very different, isn't it? If I use Grimmett as the text, would the exercises here be of help?